# Using Case When in Another Case When with SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, if-statement

This is part of `Select` part in my `SQL`.

```
(CASE WHEN GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 90, 9999, B.DOVIZ_KOD) AND  > 0 THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) AS PROV,

 (CASE WHEN B.HESAP_NO IN (SELECT HESAP_NO FROM S_TAKIP_MUSTERI) THEN 'E' ELSE 'H' END) AS CAT5,
```

What i want to add this `SQL`, **in PROV column, if CAT5 = 'E' Then Prov = 0**

How should i modify this `SQL`?

**EDIT**: I think like that

```
(CASE WHEN GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 90, 9999, B.DOVIZ_KOD) AND  > 0  THEN 100 WHEN B.HESAP_NO IN (SELECT HESAP_NO FROM S_TAKIP_MUSTERI)='E' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) AS PROV
```

but it didn't work.

**EDIT2**: Why this doesn't work??

```
(CASE WHEN GECIKME_CV(:TAR,B.HESAP_NO, 90, 9999, B.DOVIZ_KOD) > 0 THEN 100 WHEN  B.HESAP_NO IN (SELECT HESAP_NO FROM S_TAKIP_MUSTERI) THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) AS PROV
```

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work? What error messages do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use your query as a subquery:

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN  CAT5 = 'E' THEN 0 ELSE PROV END) PROV,
CAT5
FROM ( YOUR_QUERY ) anAlias
```

For example :

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN  CAT5 = 'E' THEN 0 ELSE PROV END) PROV,
CAT5
FROM ( 
-- this is your query
SELECT 'E' CAT5, 5 PROV 
-- this is your query
 ) anAlias
```

Comment: replace your query with  YOUR_QUERY. in the query i given "FROM ( YOUR_QUERY ) anAlias"